# Ссылка на поле qml родителя в динамически созданном qml объекте

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Допустим, у меня есть следующий файл:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Item {
        id: itemName
        objectName: "itemName"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        anchors.bottomMargin: 100
        width: 150
        heigth: 100
    }
}
```

Я хочу из С++ кода добавить несколько объектов в Item, определённых в другом qml файле:

```
Rectangle{
    color: "black"
}
```

При этом необходимо, чтобы Rectangle ссылался на параметр будущего родителя: *width: parent.width*. Я пробовал так:

```
QObject* root = engine.rootObjects()[0];
QQuickItem* parent = root->findChild<QQuickItem*>("itemName");
QQmlComponent test(&engine, QUrl("qrc:/someFile.qml"));
QQuickItem* child = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(test.create());
child->setParent(&engine);
child->setParentItem(parent);
child->setProperty("width", "itemName.height");
child->setProperty("height", "parent.height");
```

Но это не работает. Как можно сделать ссылку на qml родителя?

Comment: И как вы делаете это добавление? `width: parent.width` дожен работать как ожидается

Comment: добавил код, engine - QQmlApplicationEngine

Comment: Динамическое добавление qml объектов https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533565/how-to-dynamically-add-components-in-qml

Comment: Спасибо. Нет ли примера на c++?

Comment: А зачем тут С++, если qml хватает? https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdeclarativedynamicobjects.html

Comment: нужно добавить и заполнить элемент при получении определенного пакета udp сокетом.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91340/discussion-between-alexander-chernin-and-depth).